# CSS header image on scroll down

Tags: jquery, css

Does anyone know how this type of design is called, or point me to some tutorial? http://flattr.com/ I am referring to the header section of the site. The part when you scroll down and the body comes over the header, but the header is disappearing also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of web sites called "Parallaxis websites" You just find this on google so you can get many examples

Eg: http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/21-examples-of-parallax-scrolling-in-web-design